# Getting list of intersecting layers into a field in a polygon table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have a polygon layer with many other layers (different geometry but no points) in a map and I'd like to return the actual layer names where any object intersects with my polygons into a comma delimited list in a single field in my polygon layer. I'm no Python programmer; is there a function that I could use?

Comment: What are your different layers' geometries?  If all polygons you might look at using the multiple union and then aggregate tools.  If there are some lines you could buffer them first.  After the union you could instead export to a pivot table and make your comma delimited list and if needed join it back to your union.

Comment: Comma (or any) delimited lists in a field is a violation of relational best practice, so there may not be a ton of tools to help you. Putting references to multiple different layers in a single lookup table isn't common either, so you might be faced with coding it yourself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with relational best practice, it is an analysis technique for a particular purpose i.e. which constraints go through a particular site, as this has a baring on the suitability of a site for development - database structure or rule violation doesn't come into it - see John's answer re: pivot table.

Comment: John, my layers are different geometries so I will look at your helpful suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this in Field Calculator, as-is:

```sql
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_filter(array_remove_all(@layers, @layer),
                     layer_property(@element,'type') != 'Raster' AND 
                     overlay_intersects(@element)),
                 layer_property(@element,'name')),
             ', ')
```

Explanation:

1. Get a list of layers using `@layers`
2. Take out the current layer from that list using `array_remove_all(@layers,@layer)`
3. Filter that list with `array_filter()` using 2 conditions:

   a.  `layer_property(@element,'type') != 'Raster'` to exclude any raster layers (which will otherwise throw up <kbd>Eval Error: Layer '' could not be loaded</kbd>), AND

   b. `overlay_intersects()` to test if **any** feature on each layer intersects with your current layer.
4. Iterate through the filtered list with `array_foreach()` and extract the name for each layer with `layer_property(@element, 'name')` (`'name'` refers to the property we are extracting; do not replace this with the name of any layer).
5. Finally, convert the list (array) to text (string) using `array_to_string()` and your preferred delimiter.

---

Example (shown in label of polygon layer 'temp' - other layers include point layers but principle is the same):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So my query looks like this:
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_filter(array_remove_all(@layers, @layer),
                     overlay_intersects(@element)),
                 layer_property(@element,'cfs_helaa_fields')),
             ', ')
because I presume 'name' is the name of the layer to update but this gives an error:
Eval Error: Layer '' could not be loaded - so I'm wondering if I have not understood your answer clearly - could you let me know. TIA

Comment: No, that expression is to be used verbatim. You need to keep `'name'` as-is - because that is the layer property you are extracting, the layer *name*, specified as the second parameter of the `layer_property()` function (have a read through the function explanation in Field Calculator). For example if you wanted to get the layer CRS instead, you would use `layer_property(..., 'crs')`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thanks she_weeds but I'm still getting the error: Eval Error: Layer '' could not be loaded.

Comment: Can't be fully sure why that error is occurring but do you have any layers with the same name or unusual characters in the name? And which version of QGIS?

Comment: I will do some investigation but have done this with just two layers which are normal names and still I get the error! Version 3.22.16. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've just tested on a number of layers where there are no special characters, spaces etc. and it worked. I'm now going to go through all my original layers to see which one/s may be the issues - thanks again, you are a star!

Comment: If you find out what the issue was, would be curious to know what it was in the end. I did test on 3.26 but didn't think it would be something addressed by a bugfix

Comment: I've found the issue: if you have a WMS layer loaded it gives the error, unload the WMS and it works. I've done this with a number of WMS layers and it failed every time! It is ok with WFS layers so it is this that causes the issue, have no idea why or where to go from there!

Comment: Good sleuthing. Maybe it's possible to modify the expression to filter out non-vector layers, I'll have a look when I get back to a computer!

Comment: Looks like the issue is with any raster layer, WMS or file-based (understandably as `overlay_intersects()` can't work with them). I have updated the answer to resolve this issue. Hopefully this will work for you now in your original project.